# keep multiplying all integers in a list in itself till reach one integer

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply all elements in a list in itself till i get one integer.

x = 1234 to be 1x2x3x4=24, then 2x4=8

i tried numpy.prod but for some reason it works only once.

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def persistence(p):

    numbers = list(map(int, list(p)))
    multiply = [np.prod(np.array(numbers))]

    return multiply

number = input("Enter persistence number: ")
x = persistence(number)
z = persistence(x)
print(x)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a wonderful problem to introduce someone in the world of recursion. Here is how the recursive solution would look like:

```
def rec_prod(n):
  s = str(n)
  while len(s) != 1:
    n = 1
    for i in s:
      n *= int(i)
    return rec_prod(n)
  return n


res = rec_prod(1234)
print(res)  # -> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different implementation:

```
def f(x):
    r = 1
    for n in x:
        r *= int(n)
    if r > 9: #double digit
        return f(str(r))
    return r

f('1234') #8
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with basic python

Importing numpy actually increases the run time

Try using this function:

```
def persistance(n):
    while(len(n)>1):
        x=1
        for i in range(len(n)):
            x*=int(n[i])
        n=str(x)
    return n
n=input()
fin=persistance(n)
print(fin)
```

Hope it helps:")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive solution using stdlib `math.prod`:

```py
from math import prod

def product(n):
    while True:
        n = str(n)

        if len(n) == 1:
            return int(n)

        n = prod(map(int, n))
```

And we get:

```py
product(1234)  # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with that fynction:

```
from math import prod

def persistence(p):
    while len(str(p)) > 1:
        p = prod([int(i) for i in str(p)])
    return p

number = input("Enter persistence number: ")
x = persistence(number)

print(x)
```

Input:

```
Enter persistence number: 1234
```

Output:

```
8
```